# Conditions for consistent matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

In my professor's notes he said that the matrix

$$
\left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
1 & -2 & 4 \\
0 & 5 & -15 \\
0 & 3 & h+8
\end{array}\right]$$

is consistent when $3=h+8$.  Why is that?  It seems that if that is true, then $x_2=1$ which means that $5x_2=-15$ can't be true.  If this is a mistake of his (which he has been known to make) what are the values of $h$ which make this matrix consistent?

Comment: Reduce to $$\left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
1 & -2 & 4 \\
0 & 1 & -3 \\
0 & -1 & -(h+8)
\end{array}\right]$$ and add the last two rows. You must get zero

Comment: what? why?   Doesn't the matrix represent the system of equations $$x_1-2x_2=4$$ $$5x_2=-15$$ $$3x_2=h+8$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be consistent, the system of linear equations must have a solution. Given
$$x_1−2x_2=4\tag{1}$$
$$5x_2=−15\tag{2}$$
$$3x_2=h+8\tag{3}$$
we can solve $(2)$ to find $x_2=-3$. Substituting $x_2=-3$ into $(1)$ produces $x_1=-2$. Then, substituting $x_2=-3$ into $(3)$ forms
$$-9=h+8 \implies h=-17$$
so the solution is given by
$$x_1=-2, ~x_2=-3,~h=-17$$
Your professor needed to write $-9=h+8$.

Answer (score 0):

From the second line, $x_2=-3$.

From the last line, $3(-3) = h+8$, that is you are right, there is a mistake.